# Quantity as filter like price in layered navigation in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

I want to display quantity like 0-10(2) 10-20(5) 20-30(3) in layered navigation.

0-10(2)
10-20(5)
20-30(3)

But currently in Magento 2 Quantity is showing like Quantity In stock(50).

How can I achieve this with override file?
Is anyone knows how to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you any 3rd party extension?

Comment: No, I'm using Magento Default Layered Navigation only